# Installing PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt, patch-management

Quite simply, what is the easiest and most stable way to replace an apt-get installed PHP 5.2 with the new PHP 5.3 on an Ubuntu 8.10 server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had success with [these packages](http://www.dotdeb.org/2009/11/30/php-5-3-1-packages-for-debian-lenny-theyre-here/comment-page-1/) :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: installing from source is still buggy. this worked.

Answer (score 9):

well - most stable way is to stay with what distro provides.

2nd safest would be to use [official](http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid-backports/) [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports), but it seems php 5.3 is not there.

otherwise you have to rely on your own [if you [compile and build package by yourself](http://www.danielsmedegaardbuus.dk/2008-10-19/how-to-create-deb-packages-for-php-53-and-php-60/) or 3rd party contributors. quick googling returns this as one of repositories [ x86 only ] of php 5.3 for ubuntu 8.10 : http://tekla.art.pl/php-5.3-debian-ubuntu/

Comment: I could try compiling my own (have to learn it some time) but how will I prevent the rest of the system from complaining that the php5 package isn't there?

Comment: if you follow for instance follow compilation instruction i linked to - you'll get ubuntu/debian package that replaces original php5. so for instance phpmyadmin [ or anything else that depends on php ] should not complain. you'll probably have to compile from source other php libraries that you might need [ php5-gd, php5-snmp and whatever else ].

Answer (score 1):

dotdeb.org packages (as linked in the best answer) are now up to PHP 5.3.5 - worth checking the [PHP posts on the dotdeb site](http://www.dotdeb.org/category/php/) for the latest info.  Have just installed 5.3.5 on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS and looking ok so far.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 8.10 is not supported any more so i would recormend upgrading it if you are still using it (since original question originates from jul-09).
Ubuntu 8.04 (LTS) however is still supported 2 more year on server environment and couple more months on desktop.