# Is there an Ubuntu server package for PHP 5.3

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt, aptitude, dpkg

It's been some time now since the release of PHP 5.3. I can't wait to work with it, but the Ubuntu developers have decided not to include it in the APT repository until 10.04. I don't want to wait that long, it's ridiculous.

What I find strange is that there must be many, many more people who want to install PHP 5.3 on their Ubuntu server as well. Yet I cannot find a package or alternate repository anywhere on the web, only instructions on making your own (which I am not skilled enough to do and is also rather hacky).

Am I looking in the wrong direction, or is there really nothing out there that will let me install the newest PHP with dpkg/apt?

Comment: If you do make one, then you should host it somewhere (e.g. Launchpad's PPAs), so that others can use it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably your best bet is to use the PHP5.3 packages in Debian Experimental.

http://packages.debian.org/source/experimental/php5

I can not tell you how different the Debian and Ubuntu packages are, but they should work reasonably well. You might need to recompile them for your Ubuntu release if various libraries require different versions. These packages are what will appear, in some form or another, in Ubuntu 10.04.

You're totally on your own with them though. If your system breaks, you get to keep both bits. You might consider following the mailing list at pkg-php-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3 binaries from Debian and they're working fine on Ubuntu Server Jaunty.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the Debian PHP5 package for your distribution:

```
aptitude install devscripts build-essential
# You'll probably need to adjust the path to the .dsc file
dget -u -x http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php5/php5_5.3.0-3.dsc
cd php5*
debuild -us -uc # It may ask for some dependency first
ls ../*.deb
```

Comment: apt-get build-dep php5

Answer (score 0):

see my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/36040/installing-php-5-3-on-ubuntu-server/89763#89763)

(Basically, use [these packages](http://www.dotdeb.org/2009/11/30/php-5-3-1-packages-for-debian) :) )

Hope it helps!