# PHP 5.3.1 on CentOS 5.3 Or Ubuntu 8.04 / 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, php, centos, yum, apt

Forgive me for such a newbie question, but in **CentOS 5.3** or **Ubuntu 8.04 / 9.10** what is the easiest way to install (and keep updated) **PHP 5.3[.1]** via `yum` or `apt-get`, respectively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend, who are the commercial entity behind PHP, have a set of yum/apt repositories that you can use to install and update PHP 5.3 on both Ubuntu and RHEL/CentOS.

There is a community edition that can be used however you like at no cost, although not all components are open source ("free as in beer" only).

To install you would add a Zend.repo file to /etc/yum.repos.d (or edit /apt/sources.list) and then do

```
yum install zend-server-ce-php-5.3
```

or

```
apt-get update
apt-get install zend-server-ce-php-5.3
```

Full instructions are at [Choosing Which Distribution to Install](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/choosing_which_distribution_to_install.htm)

It includes an opcode cache (Zend Optimizer+) and a debugger (Zend Debugger) although these are perhaps not as widely used as APC or Xdebug, possibly because they are not open source.

It also includes Zend Framework and various extensions such as the php-java bridge, database drivers (not all of which are included in the normal PHP distributions) and a web-based management console.

There is also a commercial version which includes support and additional features.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is in your question: If you're using the distribution's packaged versions of Apache and PHP then you would install (and/or update) those packages by using `yum` or `apt-get`.  If you're really new I would suggest `aptitude` (console/terminal) or `synaptic` (X11) on Ubuntu - those are both menu-driven and supposedly more friendly.  I know equivalents exist on CentOS, but have no idea what they are :)

Re: Upgrading PHP, If your distribution has released a new package a `yum update` or `apt-get upgrade` will pick it up and install it (along with everything else that's out of date).  If all you want to update is PHP (and leave everything else alone) then you would specify the PHP package  at the end of those commands (e.g. `yum update php`).

Edit: [this nice blog post](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/427-Installing-PHP-5.3.1-On-Ubuntu-9.10-Karmic-Koala-With-aptitudeapt-get.html) gives details on how to add an apt repo with PHP 5.3.x in it  since apparently Ubuntu doesn't have an official 5.3.x package for 9.10

Comment: I'm trying several distros but the package managers only show me PHP 5.2.6/8 while PHP 5.3.1 was already released a while ago as a stable version. I will try `aptitude` on Ubuntu.

Comment: PHP 5.2.10 is the only version that comes up with `aptitude` on Ubuntu 9.10. =(

Comment: Ahh - there's the rub: Ubuntu doesn't have official Ubuntu-ized PHP 5.3.x packages!  Added a link to the answer which gives the magic incantations for getting 5.3.x going (not tested personally)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, see my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/36040/installing-php-5-3-on-ubuntu-server/89763#89763)

(Basically, use [these packages](http://www.dotdeb.org/2009/11/30/php-5-3-1-packages-for-debian) and you're good to go :) )

Hope it helps!